# conda still running after uninstall

Tags: anaconda, conda, anaconda3

I have just uninstalled `conda` following [these instruction](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/), both Options 2 and 1.

However, I can still see a working version of `conda`

```
conda --version
conda 4.10.3
```

I am working on a MacBook Air with M1 chip.

```
System Version: macOS 12.0.1
      Kernel Version: Darwin 21.1.0
      Boot Volume: Macintosh HD
```

I have also tried to restart my PC.

I wanted to uninstall `conda` because I cannot install anything due to some conflicts.

Thus my idea was to remove everything and than re-install.

Note that none of the suggestions posted here is working for me: remove directory, run `conda cleaner`, etc

Note also that `which conda` returns

```
conda () {
    \local cmd="${1-__missing__}"
    case "$cmd" in
        (activate | deactivate) __conda_activate "$@" ;;
        (install | update | upgrade | remove | uninstall) __conda_exe "$@" || \return
            __conda_reactivate ;;
        (*) __conda_exe "$@" ;;
    esac
}
```

Comment: Can you check which directory said conda resides in? I.e `which conda`

Comment: When I type `which conda` it seems to returns the definition of the function `conda`, namely

`conda () {
 \local cmd="${1-__missing__}"
 case "$cmd" in
  (activate | deactivate) __conda_activate "$@" ;;
  (install | update | upgrade | remove | uninstall) __conda_exe "$@" || \return
   __conda_reactivate ;;
  (*) __conda_exe "$@" ;;
 esac
}
`

Comment: @FlyingTeller also added to the question

Comment: Sorry, forgot that conda is shell function on UNIX systems. Can you actually run commands? In that case `conda info` should give you the actual install location. Make sure to delete that folder and also edit your `.bashrc` to remove the initialization of conda

Comment: @FlyingTeller This perfectly worked! Do you recommend that I post it as a self-answer?

Comment: Sure, go ahed with that

Answer (score 2):

Solved, thanks to @FlyingTeller.

I typed `conda info` and a list of folders appear, and also the one in which `conda` is installed.

I have removed all the directories and thus it was perfectly uninstalled.